# loadpixel() returns nullpointerexception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, processing

I was using processing in netbeans to play a movie on an array of ledstrips and I am using OPC.class for ledstrip fadecandy mapping. This code works on the processing sketch, but when I tried to use it on netbeans the loadpixel() in draw() method of OPC.java throws a nullpointer exception.

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at processing.core.PApplet.loadPixels(PApplet.java:10625)
at com.processing.OPC.draw(OPC.java:139)
at com.processing.Video.draw(Video.java:62)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2402)
at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1527)
at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:316)
```

Video.java

```
public class Video extends PApplet
{

    OPC opc;
    Movie movie;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        PApplet.main(new String[] { "--present", "com.processing.Video" });

    }

    public void settings()
    {
        size(600, 240);     
    }

    public void setup()
    {  

    opc = new OPC(this, "192.168.15.10", 7890);

        for(int i=0; i<24; i++) {
            opc.ledStrip(i * 60, 60,
            300, i * 240 / 24 + 240 / 48, 240 / 24, PI, false);
        }

    movie = new Movie(this, "waffle.mp4");
    movie.loop();

    }

    public void movieEvent(Movie m)
    {
        m.read();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw()
    {

      if (movie.available() == true) {
            movie.read(); 
            }
        image(movie, 0, 0, width, height);

    }


}
```

OPC.java

```
public class OPC extends PApplet implements Runnable  
{

  Thread thread;
  Socket socket;
  OutputStream output, pending;
  String host;
  int port;
  int height = 240;
  int width = 600;
  int[] pixelLocations;
  byte[] packetData;
  byte firmwareConfig;
  String colorCorrection;
  boolean enableShowLocations;
  PApplet parent;

  OPC(PApplet parent, String host, int port)
  {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    this.enableShowLocations = true;
    registerMethod("draw", this);
  }

  public void led(int index, int x, int y){  

    if (pixelLocations == null) {
      pixelLocations = new int[index + 1];
    } else if (index >= pixelLocations.length) {
      pixelLocations = Arrays.copyOf(pixelLocations, index + 1);
    }
    pixelLocations[index] = x + 600 * y;
  }

  public void ledStrip(int index, int count, float x, float y, float spacing, float angle, boolean reversed)
  {

    float s = sin(angle);
    float c = cos(angle);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      led(reversed ? (index + count - 1 - i) : (index + i),
        (int)(x + (i - (count-1)/2.0) * spacing * c + 0.5),
        (int)(y + (i - (count-1)/2.0) * spacing * s + 0.5));

    }

  }


  void showLocations(boolean enabled)
  {
    enableShowLocations = enabled;
  }

  void setColorCorrection(String s)
  {
    colorCorrection = s;
    sendColorCorrectionPacket();
  }

  void sendFirmwareConfigPacket()
  {
    if (pending == null) {
      return;
    }

    byte[] packet = new byte[9];
    packet[0] = (byte)0x00; // Channel (reserved)
    packet[1] = (byte)0xFF; // Command (System Exclusive)
    packet[2] = (byte)0x00; // Length high byte
    packet[3] = (byte)0x05; // Length low byte
    packet[4] = (byte)0x00; // System ID high byte
    packet[5] = (byte)0x01; // System ID low byte
    packet[6] = (byte)0x00; // Command ID high byte
    packet[7] = (byte)0x02; // Command ID low byte
    packet[8] = (byte)firmwareConfig;

    try {
      pending.write(packet);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      dispose();
    }
  }

  void sendColorCorrectionPacket()
  {
    if (colorCorrection == null) {
      return;
    }
    if (pending == null) {
      return;
    }

    byte[] content = colorCorrection.getBytes();
    int packetLen = content.length + 4;
    byte[] header = new byte[8];
    header[0] = (byte)0x00;               // Channel (reserved)
    header[1] = (byte)0xFF;               // Command (System Exclusive)
    header[2] = (byte)(packetLen >> 8);   // Length high byte
    header[3] = (byte)(packetLen & 0xFF); // Length low byte
    header[4] = (byte)0x00;               // System ID high byte
    header[5] = (byte)0x01;               // System ID low byte
    header[6] = (byte)0x00;               // Command ID high byte
    header[7] = (byte)0x01;               // Command ID low byte

    try {
      pending.write(header);
      pending.write(content);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      dispose();
    }
  }

  public void draw()
  {
    if (pixelLocations == null) {
      return;
    }
    if (output == null) {
      return;
    }

    int numPixels = pixelLocations.length;
    int ledAddress = 4;

    setPixelCount(numPixels);
    println("pixel loading");
    loadPixels();
    println("pixel loaded123");
    for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
      int pixelLocation = pixelLocations[i];
      int pixel = pixels[pixelLocation];

      packetData[ledAddress] = (byte)(pixel >> 16);
      packetData[ledAddress + 1] = (byte)(pixel >> 8);
      packetData[ledAddress + 2] = (byte)pixel;
      ledAddress += 3;

      if (true) {
        pixels[pixelLocation] = 0xFFFFFF ^ pixel;
      }
    }

    writePixels();

    if (enableShowLocations) {
      updatePixels();
      print("a");
    }
  }

  void setPixelCount(int numPixels)
  {
    int numBytes = 3 * numPixels;
    int packetLen = 4 + numBytes;
    if (packetData == null || packetData.length != packetLen) {
      // Set up our packet buffer
      packetData = new byte[packetLen];
      packetData[0] = (byte)0x00;              
      packetData[1] = (byte)0x00;              
      packetData[2] = (byte)(numBytes >> 8);   
      packetData[3] = (byte)(numBytes & 0xFF); 
    }
  }

  void setPixel(int number, int c)
  {
      println("set");
    int offset = 4 + number * 3;
    if (packetData == null || packetData.length < offset + 3) {
      setPixelCount(number + 1);
    }

    packetData[offset] = (byte) (c >> 16);
    packetData[offset + 1] = (byte) (c >> 8);
    packetData[offset + 2] = (byte) c;
  }

  int getPixel(int number)
  {
      println("get");
    int offset = 4 + number * 3;
    if (packetData == null || packetData.length < offset + 3) {
      return 0;
    }
    return (packetData[offset] << 16) | (packetData[offset + 1] << 8) | packetData[offset + 2];
  }

  void writePixels()
  {
    println("write");
    if (packetData == null || packetData.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    if (output == null) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      output.write(packetData);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      dispose();
    }
  }

  public void dispose()
  {

    if (output != null) {
      println("Disconnected from OPC server");
    }
    socket = null;
    output = pending = null;
  }

  public void run()
  {

      println("?");
      if(output == null) { // No OPC connection?
        try {              // Make one!
          socket = new Socket(host, port);
          socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
          pending = socket.getOutputStream(); 
          println("Connected to OPC server");
          sendColorCorrectionPacket();        
          sendFirmwareConfigPacket();         
          output = pending;                   
        } catch (ConnectException e) {
          dispose();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          dispose();
        }
      }

      try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
      }
      catch(InterruptedException e) {
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: Do other PApplet related functions work properly?

Comment: Oh and did you try it with super.loadPixels() ? The thing is that since you are in netbeans and run the sketch differently as in the processing environment it may not be able to get the pixels from screen in your configuration. You may also try to access the pixels[] without calling loadPixels. A last issue may also be the size() function, what happens when you call it with the renderer (P2D)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should only have one class that extends `PApplet`.**

Think of that class as your "main" class. Any other classes that need to use Processing functions will need an instance of that main class in order to access Processing functions. You can pass it in using the `this` keyword.

In fact, you're already doing that- notice that you pass `this` into your `OPC` class, and then store it in the `parent` parameter. You just never do anything with that parameter.

So **step 1** is to remove the `extends PApplet` from your `OBC` class:

```
public class OPC implements Runnable
```

This will cause some compilation errors. That's okay, we'll fix them later.

**Step 2** is to actually store the `PApplet parent` parameter in a class-level variable.

```
OPC(PApplet parent, String host, int port){
   this.parent = parent;
   //rest of constructor
```

Now that you have that, **step 3** is to fix any compilation errors by using the `parent` variable to access Processing functions.

```
parent.println("pixel loading");
parent.loadPixels();
```

More info can be found in the [Processing in eclipse tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/). It's for eclipse, but the same principles apply in netbeans.